# call a function in dll and the return value varies with the same input image parameters in release version

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, dll, visual-studio-2005

When I run my program in vs2005 whether in debug or release version,the return value is the same with the same input image parameters.however when I tried to package my program,the debug version is still ok, while the return value of release version varies with the the same input image parameters.the dll I use in my program is the corresponding (debug/release)version with the program version. By Google, some people say it may be caused by the code optimization of compiler doing with release program, but I don't know why when running my program in release version in vs environment the result is right. Is there any tips on how to dig the error out?

Comment: Did you think about debugging?

Comment: when running in visual studio,the result is right,didn't find possible error.